# ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage

Tags: ios, flutter, wkwebview

I am having trouble uploading my app to the App Store Connect. I have uploaded the same app several times before but today its showing this error:

The app references non-public selectors in Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/webview_flutter_wkwebview.framework/webview_flutter_wkwebview: initWithFrame:configuration:, isMainFrame, setNavigationDelegate:, userContentController With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.50 for id

I have not change anything that has to do with the webview_flutter dependency since the last upload.
Xcode Version 13.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message from Apple: "The issue has been resolved on the app validation backend. Please try resubmitting. Sorry for the trouble."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).